# Frozen Columns jitter on horizontal scroll in react-data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I am using the react-data-grid. When i load the grid in mobile the frozen column flickers on horizontal scroll.
This is the link to reproduce the error.

http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/fixed-cols.

Just load the grid in mobile view and try to scroll horizontally.

Anyone who has faced this issue previously ,please suggest some solution

Answer (score 3):

In my case setting `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` to `auto` did not help. Also in [this](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/1383) post [sontek](https://github.com/sontek) said that setting `rowHeight` will fix the ises what also did not work in my case.

Finally I had to remove the `border-bottom` from my custom `TableRow` component to get around this issue. Even playing around with `box-sizing` was not successful.

What I have done:

```
<div className={styles.tableRow}>
    {this.props.children}
+    <div className={styles.tableRowBorder} aria-hidden={true} />
 </div>
```

```
 .tableRow
 {
     // ...
-    border-bottom: 1px solid $colorGrayLighter3;
+    position:   relative;
 }
+
+.tableRowBorder
+{
+    height:         1px;
+    position:       absolute;
+    pointer-events: none;
+    width:          100%;
+    bottom:         0;
+    left:           0;
+    background:     $colorGrayLighter3;
+}
```

And for anyone that lands here, this is basically what the issue would look like:

UI:

[image: ui flickering]

DOM:
[image: dom flickering]

Answer (score 0):

I was observing the same behaviour. Adding the following to the data grid container helped:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
```